# Visual Studio 2019 Error when debug attach to process

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2019, revit-api

I have used visual studio 2019 (C#) to develop an add-in for Revit software.
But when I debug "attach to process". My Visual studio return a error "Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)." with exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.".
Does anybody have a solution to fix my error.
Thank you!
note: I have used plugin "Add-in manager"  to debug my code
[image]

Comment: As the error message says: you need to select the suitable debug engine when attaching (selection is available above the list of running processes).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed my error. I Uninstalled some add-in which I installed before. That fine

Answer (score 1):

If you install some nuget packages with `x64`, you should change your project to `Debug/x64` while install some `x86` nuget packages, you should change it to `Debug/x86`.

**First**, try to disable the option **Enable Just My Code** under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

**Then**, open your project in VS,right-click on the project **Properties**-->**Debug**--> check **Enable Native Code Debugging** option.

**After that**, rebuild your project and then run the program first on the current system. With it, you can use **Attach to Process** to debug this process.

**Since** I am not familiar with `revit`, you could try these suggestions to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Same Error  I am facing while .Net 6.0 to upgrade .Net8.0 and few of third party library not loading and throw exception . This solution help me to solve error .

Answer (score 0):

The message says ", but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine..."

There are two ways to debug revit addins with visual studio, either load the assembly at runtime (with invokemethod). Or start a new session of Revit.exe with the debug tools.

Comment: Nether ways run on my computer.
I use Add- in Manager to debug attach process then visual studio return a error above.